# Ordenar numeros en list

Tags: ordenar

Tengo mi script que lo que hace es darme una lista de archivos segun su coincidencia con las palabras ingresadas, pero necesito ordenar dicha lista de menor a mayor y no pude lograrlo, dejo mi codigo:

```
for i in num_file:
    num = num+1
    archivos.append('file{}'.format(num) +'.txt') 

for i in archivos:
    res = porcentajes_archivos(i) 
    resultados.append(res) a

for p,a in resultados:
    print(f'{a}: {int(p)}%')
```

Comment: en ningun lado estas ordenando no? tampoco estas armando una lista que puedas ordenar no?

Comment: @gbianchi no estoy ordenando porque si ordeno la lista "archivos" me la ordena por el nombre del file, tipo file1,file2, etc, no por el resultado en %. Intenté crear una lista que me almacene todos los % para despues de alguna manera ordenarla pero todavía no lo logré hacer

Comment: Muestra esa lista que intentaste crear, ya que esa es la que tenes que ordenar..

Comment: @gbianchi Listo, lo agregué al final, pero hasta ahi llegué de momento, no supe como seguir avanzando

Comment: creo que seria mejor guardar cada valor en una tupla y luego utilizar la funcion `sorted()` para ordenarlos segun su porcentaje

Comment: Basicamente, tal y como dice @Christian, necesitarías guardar por un lado los `file` y por otro los `%`, pero ***JUNTOS***. Para eso puedes usar tuplas y montar una lista de tuplas, que luego ordenas por el segundo valor (los %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario tendras que guardar los valores por separados pero en una tupla, de esta forma `('file1.txt',40)`, simule tu funcion para determinar el valor.

```py
import random

files = [] #aqui guardaremos los valores
 
for i in range(10):
  #esto simplemente genera los nombres y valores
  myFile = f'file{i}.txt'
  porcent = random.randint(0,100)
  #añadimos a la lista pero como TUPLAS
  files.append((porcent,myFile))

#aqui ordenamos los valores segun su % que es el primer valor

files = sorted(files, reverse=True)

#imprimimos
print(files)
```

**Salida**

```
[
('file8.txt', 89), 
('file6.txt', 60), 
('file3.txt', 45), 
('file2.txt', 37), 
('file1.txt', 29), 
('file7.txt', 23), 
('file0.txt', 17), 
('file9.txt', 17), 
('file4.txt', 13), 
('file5.txt', 9)
]
```

Si queremos ver los valores de una forma bonita solo los recorremos con un for

```py
for p,f in files:
  print(f'{f}: {p}%')
```

**Salida**

```
file8.txt: 89%
file6.txt: 60%
file3.txt: 45%
file2.txt: 37%
file1.txt: 29%
file7.txt: 23%
file0.txt: 17%
file9.txt: 17%
file4.txt: 13%
file5.txt: 9%
```

Gracias al comentario de @abulafia elimine la función lambda, no tiene mucho efecto, pero igual lee todo para que lo entiendas :)

**Implementado el código**
Tu código tiene errores, el else se ejecutara si se genera una excepcion diferente a la que especificaste. esto se arregla moviendo el contenido del `else` al `try`.

En tu función `contar_palabras` en vez de agregar el porcentaje retornamos una tupla `(porcentaje, fileName)` esto ya que la funcion solo recibe un archivo, si recibiera una lista, se retornaría la lista ordenada.

```
archivo = ''
#buscar = input("Ingrese lo que desea buscar: ")
buscar = 'de talle al suyo'
words = buscar.split(" ") #Separo la cadena de texto en palabras.
total = len(words) # Cuento la cantidad total de palabras en mi lista.
num_file = [1,2]

def contar_palabras (archivo):
    #ponemos todo en el try
    try:    
        with open(archivo, "r") as arch_obj:
            lineas = arch_obj.read()
        
        cant = 0
        for i in words: #Para cada palabra de la lista:
            if " " + i + " " in lineas or " " + i + "." in lineas or "" + i + " " in lineas or " " + i + "" in lineas or " " + i + "" in lineas : #Si la palabra existe en el archivo.
                cant = cant+1 #Suma 1 a la variable cant que indica la cantidad de palabras que existen en el file.
                perc = 100 * cant / total
            else: #Si no existe la palabra, no suma nada y solo calcula el porcentaje.
                perc = 100 * cant / total
        #la función solo lee un archivo a la vez por lo que no servira de nada ordenar la lista aqui.
        result = (perc,archivo) #creamos la tupla

        # result = sorted(result, reverse=True)
        print(archivo + ": " + str(perc) +'%') #luego mostramos
        return result #retornamos el resultado 
            
    except FileNotFoundError:
        mensaje = "El archivo " + archivo + " no existe."
        print(mensaje)


num = 0
archivos = [] #Se crea una lista vacia
resultados = [] #aqui se almacenaran los resultados

# archivos.pop(0)

for i in num_file:
    num = num+1
    archivos.append('file{}'.format(num) +'.txt') #Agrego un file a inspeccionar

for i in archivos:
    res = contar_palabras(i) #esto nos retorna una tupla (%,file)
    resultados.append(res) #lo añadimos a la lista de resultados antes creada

#una vez finalice el bucle recién se ordena la lista de resultados
resultados = sorted(resultados, reverse=True)
print(resultados)
```

Esto seria todo, puedes optimizar tus ciclos for con una compresión de lista, pero eso es otro tema.

Comment: +1. Y si las tuplas las guardas como `(porcent, myFile)` te puedes ahorrar la lambda en el `sort` :-)

Comment: @abulafia entiendo la logica de lo que hiciste, pero no pude plasmarla en mi codigo porque yo generlo el nombre y los porcentajes de mi file de manera diferente. Voy a seguir intentando igual gracias!

Comment: @abulafia tienes razon, muchas gracias

Comment: @RodrigoPaz ahora edito la respuesta con una implementacion a tu codigo

Comment: @Christian disculpa pero a ti te funciono? porque estoy intentando pero no funciona

Comment: @RodrigoPaz te da algun error en consola?, ¿por que dices que no funciona?, detalla el problema por favor

Comment: @Christian no me da error en consola, solo que no me los ordena, le paso el sorted() al list pero sigue sin ordenarlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124408/discussion-between-rodrigo-paz-and-christian).

Comment: Al agregar los valores lo debes haccer asi `files.append((porcent,myFile))`  y al ordenarlos lo haces asi `files = sorted(files, reverse=True)`, si lo haces de esta forma?